# Jenkins Multi-Job to shring build/workspace across all nodes

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation

I have created a multi-job with few Sub-Jobs (which run my each test suite), in the main job i am cloning my repo from git and store it jenkins/workspace in a linux machine. all my sub jobs run in windows nodes. is there any way to share or access my linux machines jenkins/workspace with other jobs running on windows node. Please suggest if there is any other way to acheive it.

Comment: you need to get the code from scm in your subjobs

Comment: @HenningLuther Could you please provide an example how to do that. or a suitable place where I can look into.